How to verify an elliptic function solution of PDEs and interpret its verification results?
I am sorry that I can't give you my whole code here, its too long and my mathematica version is 13.
Here is the partial differential equations,
$$ \left.\left\{\begin{array}{c}u_t-3qu^2u_x+\frac{3}{2}q(uv)_x-\frac{1}{4}qu_{xxx}=0,\\v_t+\frac{3}{2}qvv_x-3q(u^2v)_x+3qu_xu_{xx}+\frac{3}{2}quu_{xxx}-\frac{1}{4}qv_{xxx}=0,\quad q(\ne0)\in\mathbb{R}.\end{array}\right.\right.$$
Peqns = {D[u[x, t], t] - 
     3 q u[x, t]^2 D[u[x, t], x] + (3/2) q D[(u[x, t] v[x, t]), 
       x] - (1/4) q D[u[x, t], {x, 3}] == 0, 
   D[v[x, t], t] + (3/2) q v[x, t] D[v[x, t], x] - 
     3 q D[(u[x, t]^2 v[x, t]), x] + 
     3 q D[u[x, t], x] D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + (3/2) q u[x, t] D[
       u[x, t], {x, 3}] - (1/4) q D[v[x, t], {x, 3}] == 0};

I solved them, using a method called tanh expand method , this time the solution is in the form of a Jacobian elliptic function, so I use JacobiCN to represent solutions u and v.
$$\left(\text{solU2}=u\to \{x,t\}|\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2 \text{cn} \left(x-\frac{q t}{4}|-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}\right) $$ $$\left(\text{solV2}=v\to \{x,t\}|\rightarrow \frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}{\text{cn} \left(x-\frac{q t}{4}|-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2}+\frac{1}{4}\right)$$
solU2 = u -> 
  Function[{x, t}, -(1/(2 JacobiCN[-((q t)/4) + x, -(Sqrt[3]/2)]))]
solV2 = v -> 
  Function[{x, t}, 
   1/4  + (-(1/2))^2/JacobiCN[-((q t)/4) + x, -(Sqrt[3]/2)]^2]

I have not learned any knowledge about elliptic functions, but I also verified the solution as usual (some previous solutions were in the form of tanh).
FullSimplify[
 Peqns /. {
   solU2, solV2
   }
 , {q \[Element] Reals, x \[Element] Reals, t \[Element] Reals, 
  q != 0}]

The output is,
{JacobiSN[(q t)/4 - x, -(Sqrt[3]/2)]/
  JacobiCN[(q t)/4 - x, -(Sqrt[3]/2)] == 0, 
 JacobiSN[(q t)/4 - x, -(Sqrt[3]/2)]/
  JacobiCN[(q t)/4 - x, -(Sqrt[3]/2)] == 0}

which is different from the previous True result (solutions in tanh form). Although I don't show how the solutions were generated, but I am sure they are in the form of a Jacobian elliptic function.Here is my two questions,

How to verify the solution in JacobiCN form, am I doing this the right way?
If it is right, how to interpret the results, is it equivalent to True, or if it's wrong , then how to verify a solution with JacobiCN form,will the right result be True?

Thanks a lot!

Your solutions fullfill the Peqns only if the condition JacobiSN[(q t)/4 - x, -(Sqrt[3]/2)]/   JacobiCN[(q t)/4 - x, -(Sqrt[3]/2)] == 0 holds. That means your solution doesn't solve the pde in general!

@UlrichNeumann If a solution solve the pde in general, the outputs will give True? I thought it was an issue about JacobiSN simplification.

@UlrichNeumann I changed my code and it worked , it's not a math problem, it's a programming problem.

I tried changing the way I substituted the solution, and it worked.
First, I simplified the solutions,
solU2 = -(1/(2 JacobiCN[-((q t)/4) + x, -(Sqrt[3]/2)]))
solV2 = 1/4 (1 + 1/JacobiCN[(q t)/4 - x, -(Sqrt[3]/2)]^2)

PDEs are the same,
Peqns = {D[u[x, t], t] - 
     3 q u[x, t]^2 D[u[x, t], x] + (3/2) q D[(u[x, t] v[x, t]), 
       x] - (1/4) q D[u[x, t], {x, 3}] == 0, 
   D[v[x, t], t] + (3/2) q v[x, t] D[v[x, t], x] - 
     3 q D[(u[x, t]^2 v[x, t]), x] + 
     3 q D[u[x, t], x] D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + (3/2) q u[x, t] D[
       u[x, t], {x, 3}] - (1/4) q D[v[x, t], {x, 3}] == 0};

Then I tried another way to replace u and v,
FullSimplify[
 Peqns /. {
   u -> Function[{x, t}, solU2],
   v -> Function[{x, t}, solV2]
   }
 , {q \[Element] Reals, x \[Element] Reals, t \[Element] Reals, 
  q != 0}]

And it quickly gave the answer {True, True}, and I don't know why it work...
